# Vector option in Java

Tags: java

I am using vector of object. My issue is the removal from vector is expensive operation( O(n^2)). What would be the replacement of vector in Java. In my uses addition and removal is extensively happens.

i am C++ person don't know much Java

Comment: Your information about the runtime of the `remove` operation is wrong. Apart from that, use `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`.

Comment: what would be behavior of ArrayList on addition and deletion?

Comment: @Saurabh01 The same as `Vector` – it’s essentially the same, but without the useless synchronization. `Vector` is largely obsolete and has been replaced by `ArrayList`. And as I’ve said, the runtime of `remove` is linear so it’s much better than O(n^2).

Comment: @Saurabh: why u are "adding and removing extensively" .may i know who is adding and removing from the vector.what business logic it tries to implement.

Comment: Can you please add more information on what you need from your collection? Do you need to iterate over it and remove items? Do you also add? Do you care about order? Do you need O(1) for accessing items? Or is O(n) good? Perhaps a set/map will be better for you?

Comment: @Konard: I am looking for linear overhead in deletion as well as fast insertions. Thanks

Comment: @Saurabh01: is there thread involving in adding and deleting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for there contribution which helped me to solve this problem. I used a circular queue which has been written with help of vector.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Vector class shouldn't be used. There are so many containers available in Java. Few of them:

`ArrayList` is good for random access, but is bad for inserting or removing from the middle of the list.

`LinkedList` is bad for random access, but is fair good for iterating and adding/removing elements from the middle of container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArrayList instead of vector in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2001-06/03-qa-0622-vector.html

LinkedList can add/remove items at O(1)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Vector removal time complexity is O(n) not O(n^2). If you want more performant class, you should choose LinkedList. Its time complexity is constant.

Comment: i think, Vector using System.arrayCopy which complexity is O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a list is not the ideal data structure for your use case - would you be better off using a HashSet if the ordering of elements is not imporant?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the difference between `Vector` and `ArrayList` is that `Vector` is synchronized whereas `ArrayList` is not. Generally, you don't need synchronization and thus you'd use `ArrayList` (much like `StringBuffer` <-> `StringBuilder`).

The replacement mostly depends on how you intend to use the collection.

Adding objects to an `ArrayList` is quite fast, since if more space is required, it is normally doubled, and if you know the size requirements in advance, even better.

Removing from an `ArrayList` is O(n) but iteration and random access are fast.

If you have frequent add or remove operations and otherwise iterate over the list, a `LinkedList` would be fine.

You could even consider using a `LinkedHashMap` which allows fast access as well as preserves the order of insertion.

Comment: I am using it to add integral data type as well as some custom object. I also like to preserve the order of insertion.

Comment: I don't know the approximate size in advance.

Comment: So you have a list of objects which can be of any type? Hmm, that's a dangerous design. Could you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

> i think, Vector using System.arrayCopy which complexity is O(n^2)

It is correct that `Vector` will use `System.arrayCopy` to move the elements.  However the `System.arrayCopy()` call copies at most `Vector.size()` elements, and hence is `O(N)` where `N` is the vector's size.

Hence `O(N^2)` is incorrect for a single insertion / removal.

---

In fact, if you want better than `O(N)` insertion and deletion, you will need to use some kind of linked list type with a cursor abstraction that allows insertion and deletion at "the current position".  Even then you only get better than `O(N)` if you can do the insertions / deletions in the right order; i.e. not random order.

FWIW, the Java `List` APIs don't provide such a cursor mechanism ... not least because it would be awkward to use, and only efficient in certain circumstances / implementations.